# Passing variable num of args to another method in class

Tags: c++, class, variadic-functions

I've got following (simplified for example purpose) code and it works:

```
void log(const string type, const string msg, va_list argp)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "[%s] ", type.c_str());
    vfprintf(stdout, msg.c_str(), argp);
}

void log_err(const string msg, ...)
{
    va_list argp;

    va_start(argp, msg);
    log("ERROR", msg, argp);
    va_end(argp);
}
```

I would use it in this way:

```
log_err("test: %d", 5);
```

However if I would like to move this to class:

```
class Logger {
public:
    Logger() {
        //
    };
    void generic(const string type, const string msg, va_list argp) {
        fprintf(stdout, "[%s] ", type.c_str());
        vfprintf(stdout, msg.c_str(), argp);
    };
    void error(const string msg, ...) {
        va_list argp;

        va_start(argp, msg);
        this->generic("ERROR", msg, argp);
        va_end(argp);
    };
};
```

Then I got Segmentation fault. I know that tricky thing like va macros could not work within class scopes but I want to know why.

Thanks in advice!

**EDIT**

Example usage:

```
Logger logger;
logger.error("test", 5);
```

Full source:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdarg>

using namespace std;

void log(const string type, const string msg, va_list argp)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "[%s] ", type.c_str());
    vfprintf(stdout, msg.c_str(), argp);
}

void log_err(const string msg, ...)
{
    va_list argp;

    va_start(argp, msg);
    log("ERROR", msg, argp);
    va_end(argp);
}

class Logger {
    public:
        Logger() {
            //
        };
        void generic(const string type, const string msg, va_list argp) {
            fprintf(stdout, "[%s] ", type.c_str());
            vfprintf(stdout, msg.c_str(), argp);
        };
        void error(const string msg, ...) {
            va_list argp;

            va_start(argp, msg);
            this->generic("ERROR", msg, argp);
            va_end(argp);
        };
};

int main()
{
    //log_err("test: %s\n", "str");

    Logger logger;
    logger.error("test %s", 5);

    return 0;
}
```

I don't want to make these methods static because in original use i have private file descriptors to which I'm writing log messages;

Comment: The code you pasted looks fine. Where does the segmentation fault occur? What does the call of `error` look like? (And get rid of the `this->`, it's not needed.)

Comment: How are you actually calling `error()`?  The 'tricky' thing about classes and varargs is that you can't pass a non-POD object in the variable argument list.

Comment: You show definitions for functions `log()` and `log_err()`.  Your `log_err()` function calls `verror_log()`, which is not shown. In C, you'd have to worry about your `log()` conflicting with `log()` from the mathematics portion of the standard C library; in C++, you don't have the same issues.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: It's segfaulting when I'm running example I've posted in update to the question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: There should by `log`. The second function is calling the first. I've fixed this in example.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I've changed all `string` params to `char*` but it's still segfaulting. This isn't the case I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug is in this line:

```
      logger.error("test %s", 5);
```

The `%s` format specifier is for a C-style string. `5` is not a C-style string. Use:

```
      logger.error("test %s", "5");
```

or:

```
      logger.error("test %d", 5);
```

Comment: Wow! It worked! I've slipped over such obvious thing, thanks David!

Comment: @SebastianSito: if you're using GCC you can mark the function as using a `printf()` style format string and have the compiler warn you about problems like this.  Something like: `__attribute__ ((format (printf, 2, 3)))` would do the trick (I think). For details see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html

Answer (score 0):

You're 99% of the way there.  change

```
 void generic(const string type, const string msg, va_list argp)
```

to

```
void generic(const string type, const string msg, va_list & argp)
```

Seems you can't copy the list (which is done without the reference)

EDIT:: what I posted above is wrong.  The first pass through I just assumed what was provided seg faulted and didn't test without the reference.  I removed the reference and everything printed just fine.

Left for people of the future.

Comment: So You're telling me that above example works for You? Can You paste Your code along with complilation flags?